# Geoviews FilledContours: keeping filled colours but removing countour lines

Tags: python, plot, kernel-density, geoviews

I would like to plot something that resembles a kdeplot using [geoviews](https://geoviews.org/gallery/bokeh/filled_contours.html) without actually plotting the contour lines. The [geoplot](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/plot_references/plot_reference.html) library supports something like this:

[image]

**How can I make such a plot in geoviews?**

Here is a very basic example of the kind of kdeplot I am managing to generate via geoviews, which by default plots the black lines that separates different intensities:

```
import geoviews.tile_sources as gts
import geoviews as gv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
gv.extension('bokeh')

np.random.seed(2021)

# Define extent of GPS coordinates
xmean = -12.015358
ymean = -76.990665
xmin, xmax = xmean*0.9, xmean*1.1
ymin, ymax = ymean*0.9, ymean*1.1
xrange = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, num=1000)
yrange = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, num=1000)
# Sample GPS coordinates
latlon = np.vstack([np.random.choice(xrange, 100), np.random.choice(yrange, 100)]).T

# Fit a gaussian kernel
kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=0.03)
kde.fit(latlon)

# Apply gaussian kernel on grid
X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
Z = kde.score_samples(positions.T).reshape(X.shape)

# Define Map
kde_plot = gv.FilledContours((Y, X, Z)).opts(cmap='PuBu', fill_alpha=0.5)
background_plot = gts.CartoLight
geomap = (kde_plot * background_plot).opts(width=800, height=550, xaxis=None, yaxis=None)
geomap
```

[image]

I could not find any parameter settings in `gv.FilledCountours` that remove these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument you have to use is `line_color` and in your case you want to set it to `None`.

Applying the change to this line of code

```
kde_plot = gv.FilledContours((Y, X, Z)).opts(cmap='PuBu', fill_alpha=0.5, line_color=None)
```

you will get this plot as a return.

[image: No line color]

Comment: This no longer works unfortunately. I am trying to figure out something similar in 2024 using geoviews `1.11.1`